# Syntax in structures [c]

Tags: c, data-structures

I was doing a Bingo - type project when i started to get some errors in my first "for" loop and in the end of the "bingo" structure.

Can someone tell me what have I done wrong?

```
struct bingo{
    int table[5][5];

    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        *(table + i) = rand()%75 + 1;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            if ((j != i) && ((*(table + i)) == (*(table + j))))
            {
                i--;
                j = 5 * 5;
            }

        }


    }
};
```

errors:
    1   IntelliSense: expected a type specifier ( first for)
    2   IntelliSense: expected an identifier (end of the sturct)

Comment: Structures only contains data types and pointers.

Comment: So you say that i need to move the "for" from the struct?

Comment: Statements can only be in functions.

Comment: Yes. You need to move it from struct.

Comment: Well, thank you @haccks!
New to structs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs are only able to contain variables, they can't have any logic in them. In C++ you can have functions defined in structs, but even then you need a function header and body.